# Pattern Match MySql Search?

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

Is there a way to search on ### String patterns in Mysql? For instance I want to find inside text blocks when/if terms like lbs or feet etc are used as a measurement, could I do some:

Feet

.#### lbs

to return e.g.
- 4 Feet
- 102 Feet
- 1000 Feet
- 5.6 lbs
- 100.52 lbs

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` clause to match sub string patterns.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE col LIKE '%pattern%';
```

The `%` signifies any text (or none) can be in this position. So the above example says I want text with the word 'pattern' in it, and I don't care what comes before or after it.

You could also use `_` to signify you want a specific number of characters in that position. Each underscore represents 1 character.

```
...
WHERE col LIKE '_pattern'
```

This would give me text that matches any 1 character and then the string 'pattern'.